# Get specifics about operating system

Tags: operating-system, firefox-addon, platform

I thought this would be easy but I can't figure this out.

How to tell if using Win7 or WinXP? Like details on operating system. Linux should give specifics. Mac OS version etc.

I thought to read user agent from `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow` and `window.navigator` but on browser startup `hiddenDOMWindow` isn't loaded yet.

Right now I can only get `WINNT` from:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm")
console.log(OS.Constants.Sys.Name)
```

or

```
console.log(Services.appinfo.OS)
```

`console.log` of `window.navigator` gives all this good stuff, how to get this without having access to `window`?

```
appCodeName:"Mozilla"
appName:"Netscape"
appVersion:"5.0 (Windows)"
battery:BatteryManager
buildID:"20140529161749"
cookieEnabled:true
doNotTrack:"yes"
geolocation:Geolocation
language:"en-US"
mimeTypes:MimeTypeArray
mozAlarms:null
mozApps:XPCWrappedNative_NoHelper
mozCameras:CameraManager
mozConnection:MozConnection
mozContacts:ContactManager
mozId:null
mozKeyboard:XPCWrappedNative_NoHelper
mozPay:null
mozPermissionSettings:null
mozPhoneNumberService:PhoneNumberService
mozPower:MozPowerManager
mozTCPSocket:null
onLine:true
oscpu:"Windows NT 5.1"
platform:"Win32"
plugins:PluginArray
product:"Gecko"
productSub:"20100101"
userAgent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
vendor:""
vendorSub:""
__proto__:NavigatorPrototype
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the system info service. To get the OS version

```js
Services.sysinfo.getProperty("version");
```

Consult the [sources](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/xpcom/base/nsSystemInfo.cpp) for the properties supported. Also pay attention to their platform-specific meaning (e.g. on Android there is `version` and `kernel_version`)

Comment: Thanks man! I added this to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/NsIPropertyBag#Methods and credited you :)

Answer (score 2):

Some other ways I found to do this are:

- Then check wikipedia here for windows version. [Wikipedia Windows Versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions) If it's `NT 5.1` than it's WinXP

  ```
  var os_string = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http"].getService(Ci.nsIHttpProtocolHandler).oscpu; //this is something like `Windows NT 6.3; WOW64` and you look for 6.3 which means Windows 8.1
  ```

## EDIT

Just discovered that `Cc["@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http"].getService(Ci.nsIHttpProtocolHandler)` has the `userAgent` just like navigator above.

So just go like:

`Cc["@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http"].getService(Ci.nsIHttpProtocolHandler).userAgent` and it gives you `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0` just like `navigator.userAgent`.

Here is all that is in `Cc["@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http"].getService(Ci.nsIHttpProtocolHandler)`:

```
appName:"Mozilla"
appVersion:"5.0"
defaultPort:80
misc:"rv:33.0"
oscpu:"Windows NT 6.3; WOW64"
platform:"Windows"
protocolFlags:76
scheme:"http"
userAgent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
```

For mac your useragent line and oscpu line will tell you all about the operating system.
For example on Mac OS X 10.9 it spts out `Intel Mac OS X 10.9`. It's nice you get the 10.X

`Services.sysinfo.getProperty("version");` puts out `13.4.0` on OSX 10.9 and on OSX 10.10.1 it puts out `14.0.0` so probably not an accurate way for mac, but its good for windows. For 10.10.1 the useragent oscpu is just 10.10 it doesnt show the .1

Comment: note: `navigator.platform` is different from `Cc["@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http"].getService(Ci.nsIHttpProtocolHandler).platform` the first returns Win32 and second returns Windows. On mac first returns `MacIntel` second one rturns `Macintosh`