# Within ChromeWorker deteciting OS Details

Tags: operating-system, firefox-addon

I'm trying to detect the OS details like OSX 10.6.x or 10.8.x or 10.10.1 (Or win7 winXp etc) in ChromeWorker. I know i can send it from the other side but i was looking for an internal way.

This is the way i do it on the other side: [Get specifics about operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032279/get-specifics-about-operating-system)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChromeWorker`s don't have XPCOM access, just js-ctypes access.
Implementing this stuff in js-ctypes is a lot of error-prone busywork and you need to provide implementations for different OSes, so I recommend against that.

Then there is [`OS.Constants`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.Constants#OS.Constants.Sys) in particular `OS.Constants.Sys.Name`, however this will just tell you the generic name, like "Darwin", but nothing more and might therefore not fine-grained enough.

Otherwise follow [the answer you already found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032279/get-specifics-about-operating-system) and pass the data you require to the Chrome Worker.

Comment: Aw dang ok thanks, so passing data is the most efficient way. Thanks!