# How to find out browser's user agent in Firefox Add On

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm creating (developing) a Firefox add-on and I need to find browser's user agent.
The `navigator.userAgent` is not working. It shows that the `navigator` is not defined.

What Firefox Add-on module do I need to get user agent or is there another way to find it out in an add-on?

Comment: Check out this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032279/get-specifics-about-operating-system

Comment: `Services.sysinfo.getProperty("version");`
Getting that Services is not defined
`ReferenceError: Services is not defined`

Comment: From addon sdk you have to import chrome like this: `var {Cc, Cu, Ci} = require('chrome'); Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');` then you can use `Services`

Comment: Also read further down in the question. In the solutoin i posted it shows you how to get exactly the `navigator.userAgent`

Comment: Thanks! This really helps @Noitidart.
Can you put this as a Answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 5):

In the SDK, first you need the [chrome authority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority) for `Cc` and `Ci`:

```
const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
```

The you can use the `nsIHttpProtocolHandler` to get the user agent from there:

```
const httpproto = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http"].
                  getService(Ci.nsIHttpProtocolHandler);

console.log(httpproto.userAgent);
```

Using the hidden window and hacks like that will work too, for now, but that's somewhat messy and might be problematic in the multi-process future.