# Hidden window alternative

Tags: firefox-addon

I use hidden window extensively but i read that might be problematic in the multi-process future. I use it mainly for `canvas` element so I can load png's onto it and then overlay other pngs on it and then save it as a png. I do scaling too. What would be the alternative, without hidden window assuming no windows available?

Thanks

Comment: can you link to where you read that?

Comment: Hey @the8472 i read it by nmaier here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28718535/1828637

Answer (score 1):

For SDK Addons you could use the [page-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker) module, load a html page from a `resource://` into it and interact with it through content scripts and the port api.

Sending images through the port api would be quite inefficient since it json-serializes right now, but hopefully they'll switch to structured clone in the future.

Of course right now the page worker API just uses the hidden window under the hood, but if the implementation were to change (e.g. being moved to the content process) the module the module API should stay the same.

Comment: Thanks for that note man. Just curious aside from hiddenDOMWindow to get canvas element, is the only way to deal with images, just doing it myself like working with bytes DataView ArrayBuffer etc?